# How to apply drain cleaner to A/C drain

Tags: repair, air-conditioning, cleaning

A while back I asked a question in a thread ([The top A/C drain in my attic is leaking. Why?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168117/the-top-a-c-drain-in-my-attic-is-leaking-why)), and I wanted to know how to apply drain cleaner to the bottom drain on my A/C system. Could someone answer my question?

Comment: Do you have a picture of the drain assembly?  Sometimes the installer will add a capped of vertical section just to clean out the drain or add cleaner.  If not, you will have to add that yourself.

Comment: You should be using a coil cleaner, some drain cleaners will etch the aluminum fins and sealed lines possibly causing failure of the coil.